# C# - Sending a XML over to Action result via JavaScript in cshtml

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I have a `.cshtml` file which contains JavaScript function to perform a POST action to my controller class.

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="username" />
<button type="submit" onclick="sendResult()">Submit</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function sendResult() {
        let username = document.getElementById('username').value;

        try {
            let xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.open("POST", "/Test/Test");
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
            let xml = `<?xml version="1.0"?><query><Username>${username}</Username></query>`;
            console.log(xml)
            xmlhttp.send(xml);

            let xmlResponse;
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = async function () {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
                    xmlResponse = await xmlhttp.responseXML;
                    console.log(xmlResponse)
                }
            }
            
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
</script>
```

In my controller class, I did not manage to receive the xml string (myXML) after clicking on the submit button. Why is that so?

```cs
// TestController.cs 
        public ActionResult Test()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Test(string myXML)
        {
            Service1Client o = new Service1Client();
            o.Test(myXML);

            return View();
        }
```

Comment: did you try [FromnBody] in controller?

Comment: I tried but it says: The type of namespace name 'FromBody' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I tried to use Request.Body, check https://github.com/anirugu/SO74497582

Comment: Hey, I saw it! am able to receive my xml now! Thank you!!